# Using sql if else for Anonymizing data in table more simple

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, parameters, anonymous

the table outputs four columns , i take in a parameter cid and i want the column for company names to all be set as XXXXXX but not the row that contains the Cid

```
  select x1.CompanyID, x1.CompanyName,x1.averagesurveyscore as Company_Score, x1.Totalticket as Total_Tickets 
  from @table1 x1
  where x1.companyid = @cid
```

so pretty much set all data that is not the cid to XXXXXX in the company name column except for the company that has been given in the parameter. I dont want anyone seeing the company names.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is vague, at least to me, but you can try with `case`

```
select x1.CompanyID
     , case when x1.CompanyName = @cid then x1.CompanyName else 'XXXXXX' end
     , x1.averagesurveyscore as Company_Score
     , x1.Totalticket as Total_Tickets 
from @table1 x1
```

Comment: if i wanted to do the same to another column as well would i put it in the same case statement or create a new one?

Comment: @bigdowg: you should use another one.

Answer (score 1):

```
select x1.CompanyID, 
IF (x1.companyid = @cid, x1.CompanyName, 'XXX') AS CompanyName, 
x1.averagesurveyscore as Company_Score, 
x1.Totalticket as Total_Tickets 
from @table1 x1
```